# rails embedded ruby conditional not behaving correctly on click event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, click, conditional-statements

I am trying to call a function (ajaxReq(val);) from within a js script in an erb file. I want to call the function on a click event only IF @years_true == true. When I do <% puts @years_true %> within the click event, it returns the correct value.  However, when I wrap it in a ruby if statement (so that it only calls the function when @years_true evaluates to true) it *never* calls the function on a click even when @years_true is true. Here's all the code I think could be relevant, and many thanks.

UsersController:

```
@years_true = !@user.years.find_by_year(params[:age]).nil?
```

_showjs.html.erb:

```
$(".year").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var val = $(this).text();
$.get( "/<% if !@user.nil?%><%= @user.name %><% end %>/" + val, function(data) {
});
<% if @years_true %>
  ajaxReq(val);
<% end %>
history.replaceState({}, '', "/" + gon.username + '/' + val );
return false;
});
```

Comment: If you do something like 'console.log('testing')' or 'alert('test')' within that conditional, will it execute?